# TypeError: AWS.Chime is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I'm trying to build a video chat/conference platform using **[amazon-chime-sdk-js](https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-js)**.

But while trying to create instanse for `AWS.Chime()` using **[aws-sdk-js](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js)**, I'm getting the following error:

[image]

I've tried so far according to basic documentation:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const chime = new AWS.Chime({ region: 'us-east-1' });
chime.endpoint = new AWS.Endpoint('https://service.chime.aws.amazon.com/console');
```

Additionally `import AWS from 'aws-sdk';` doesn't work either as it doesn't have default export value.

Any solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`AWS.Chime({ region: "eu-west-1" })` should be added on server side application and NOT on client side.

```
"dependencies": {
  "amazon-chime-sdk-js": "^1.3.0",  // <-- A browser 
  "aws-sdk": "^2.656.0" // <-- It should be included in your server-side application
}
```

**Here's a high-level flow:**

- A user joins your browser app and asks your server application to create or join a meeting.
- Your server application creates a meeting and an attendee using AWS SDK (e.g. aws-sdk in Node.js). The server application returns responses back to your browser app.
- In your browser app, a user starts the amazon-chime-sdk-js session using responses from your server.

https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-js/issues/303#issuecomment-618566215